# How to create a wrapper for Retrofit API using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have two APIs say API 1 and API 2. API 1 get authentication token and API 2 get user profile info. I need to hit API 2 from ViewModel but if API 2 gives an authentication error, then I need to get new token first and then hit API 2(user info)

Currently, I use RxJava Single and Retrofit for all APIs but for APIs one by one. There are a lot of APIs that use authentication token and if it expires in any of the APIs then I need to call authentication API and get the token again and then call the APIs with a new authentication token.

What should be the best way to design a wrapper so that it can be used with all APIs with code reusability as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea. If you have basemodel for getting response for API, you can make custom getter for response code and check if response code in token_expired.

This is sample response that I got From API.

```
{ 
    response_code: "200",
    response_msg: "",
    result: ...
}
```

And this is my BaseModel.

```
class BaseModel<T> {
    @SerializedName("response_code")
    var response_code: Int? = null
        get() {
            if(field == ErrorStatusCode.TOKEN_EXPIRE) {
                ErrorCodeHandler.requestNewToken()
            }
            return field
        },
    @SerializedName("response_msg")
    var response_msg: String? = null
    @SerializedName("result")
    var data: T? = null
}
```

So whenever token expire, I will request Net token by call `ErrorCodeHandler.requestNewToken()`

But If you want to recall API that found token timeout I have no idea what to do too.

PS. Hope this help.